# Gamecenter server problems? Testing game multiplayer with sandbox

Tags: iphone, game-center, multiplayer

Is something wrong with game center? I've been testing my app multiplayer through sandbox accounts it was working properly. But since the last weekend any invitations send are not being received or i get the message 'couldnt connect'. The 'play now' was working, but now it also ain't working. Anyone facing the same problem? Can i check gamecenter status anywhere? It's driving me crazy

When i hit the play now button, it goes straight to this method:

```
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch *)theMatch {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.match = theMatch;
    self.match.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Peer-to-Peer");
    if (!matchStarted && self.match.expectedPlayerCount == 0) {        
        NSLog(@"Ready to start match! from matchmakerviewcontroller");
        [self lookupPlayers];
    }
}
```

When it was working, i used to get into the 'if' part. Now the expectedPlayerCount that i receive is 1, like if it didnt find any player. How so?

Thanks is advance.